# how to make a spiral that goes through a specific point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spiral

I am in unity and trying to make an object have a spiral shaped trajectory that goes through a point.
the movement I am trying to make is in 2D.

Here is where I make the spiral shape:

[image]

and I want to know the necessary var_length , radian, length and var_radian necessary to go through a specific point.

I was wondering if anyone here already had to make that kind of movement.

I tried to use the radian that if you follow from the starting point of the spiral you get to the target in a straight line, the radian that the projectile has in the beginning, calculate the distance between the 2 points to figure out the number of time I need to change the radian and length.

what I tried did not handle the movement of the target point very well.

The way my code is made makes it that var_len and radian (at the start), you know their values.

Comment: **[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)**

Comment: with so many variables there is probably many possible combinations that hit a specific point .. you would probably need to limit them a bit further / have more input .. you basically are looking for 4 unkowns having only two positions and your formula ...

Comment: Sorry I haven't put in the message, but I know var_length and radian

Comment: Minor issue - It sets `newPos` to a value and then immediately overwrites that value. This is confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: @furu its just a little bit confusing that you state `I want to know the necessary var_length , radian, length and var_radian` .. doesn't sounds like you actually already know the `var_length` and `radian` ;)

Comment: yeah sorry about that, var_length and radian are just variable that you know when you need to get length and var_radian